# devise confirmation not working while upgrading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I was previously Using Rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3 with devise version 3.2. I am not sure about devise version.

Now i upgraded rails version to 4.1.8 and now the login shows error please confirm your account before continuing.

I tried to update in rails console by finding the user and confirm with confirm!, it shows column confirmed_at getting updated.

again when i find the user , the confirmed at column still nil. If i try to login the user needs to be confirmed.

I created the new rails app version 4.1.8, ruby 2.1.3 and devise 3.4.1 , now signed up and confirmed its working fine. and also in console tried confirming, the confirmed_at field getting updated.

Don't know whether upgrading rails throws this error, still rails 3.2 working fine(Note, confirmed_at is nil here)

Comment: Post the output of $ rails console in which you call confirm! but then confirmed_at is still nil.